# Inheritance and Generics in Java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

so I am making a project and I have some questions about inheritance.
I have two classes, named Attribute and NumericalAttribute. The first one:

```
public class Attribute {
    Attribute() {}
    Attribute(String type) {}
}
```

(which should be abstract, but i need to instantiate it so it can't be)

and the other one:

```
public class NumericalAttribute extends Attribute {
    double value;

    NumericalAttribute(String value) { this.value = Double.parseDouble(value); }

    public double getAtr(Attribute atr) { return this.value; }
}
```

I have multiple children of Attribute, and each one of them has the same structure but it represents another type (string, int, boolean). The thing is I need some kind of method to return the "value" variable (which I do have in NumericalAttribute) but for the attribute class. But I can't create a method in Attribute, since each one of the sons will have a different type of return. So is there any way so that I can obtain the "value" variable through Attribute?
Thank you very much!

```
  public static Atributo transformAtributo(String tipo, String valor) {
        Atributo atr = new Atributo();
        if (tipo.equals("bool")) atr = new AtributoBoolean(valor);
        else if (tipo.equals("string")) atr = new AtributoCategorico(valor);
        else if (tipo.equals("num")) atr = new AtributoNumerico(valor);
        else if (tipo.equals("set")) atr = new AtributoCategoricoMultiple(valor);
        else if (tipo.equals("fecha")) atr = null;

        return atr;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what you are looking for:

```
public abstract class Attribute<T> {

    public abstract T getValue(Attribute attr);

}

public class NumericalAttribute extends Attribute<Double> {

    double value;

    @Override
    public Double getValue(Attribute attr) {
        return value;
    }
}

public class TextAttribute extends Attribute<String> {

    String value;

    @Override
    public String getValue(Attribute attr) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

`Attribute<T>` is a generic class. The return type is declared on each concrete class.

Comment: I get it, but I get an error saying that I need to add a return statement inside attribute<T>

Comment: @Pau `Attribute` should be an abstract class. What type would the value of an `Attribute` be?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see it was abstract. Is there any other way I can do it though? because I need to instantiate the Attribute class. The program goes like this: I read multiple Strings from a csv file, and I have a parallel csv file containing the types of each word. Then, what I do is instantiate an Attribute class (which can be string, int, double, ...) and then I linked it according to the type

Comment: I added the code in the original paragraph (sorry it's in spanish), and since now the class is abstract, I can't instantiate the Atrtibute class, and I don't really know how to change it now

Comment: Oh nevermind, it worked what I changed. Thank you so much!